# Assert that element cannot respond to mouseover

Tags: exception, mouseevent, cypress

I am trying to assert that, when I `mouseover` a covered element, the element on top is activated and not the hidden one.

However, when using `.trigger('mouseover')` on the hidden object, an error occurs because I cannot `mouseover` that object, and the test stops.

Is there a way to try to `mouseover` and assert that a failure occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for now is probably to use [this .shouldNotBeClickable() command](https://gist.github.com/SecondFlight/777fbfc595e58b3aae125b657535565f), because if the element cannot be clicked then it also cannot be hovered. Use this command with caution, as **it skips all remaining commands in your `it()` block when used** due to a bug in Cypress.

---

As of right now (Cypress 3.1.0), this is not possible. It should be as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52073331/assert-that-element-is-not-actionable-in-cypress/52142935#comment91625327_52142935), but `cy.once()` has some code-breaking bugs that I've run into trying to adapt the command in that answer.

**The following custom command does *not* work** as of Cypress 3.1.0. It *should* work, but it causes Cypress to hang.

index.js:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("shouldNotBeHoverable", {
    prevSubject: true
}, function(subject) {
    let errorMessage = "shouldNotBeHoverable: element hover succeeded, but it souldn't have";

    let done = false;
    cy.wrap(subject[0]).trigger('mouseover', { force: true });
    cy.once('fail', (err) => {
        if (err == errorMessage)
            throw errorMessage;

        expect(err.message).to.include('cy.trigger() failed because this element');
        expect(err.message).to.include('is being covered by another element');
        done = true;
    });

    cy.wrap(subject[0]).trigger('mouseover', {timeout: 1000});

    cy.get('html').then(() => {
        if (!done)
            throw errorMessage;
    });
});
```

Cypress test:

```js
cy.get("#selector").shouldNotBeHoverable();
```

---

The related Github issues are linked below. This specific issue isn't reported, but both issues are similar enough that I suspect the underlying cause is the same.

[Mixing cy.on()/cy.once() with a one-argument it() function causes test to hang](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2478)

[Queued commands silently skipped when using cy.once() in a custom command](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2474)